# From WCF to API call - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, .net, rest, sockets, wcf

I am calling a external API from a WCF service and getting below error.

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it xx.xx.xxx.1:443
```

If am making same API from console application then it is working fine.

How can I make same API request working from locally hosted WCF service?

Comment: Is the console and WCF built with same version of Net in the project properties. Compare project properties to see if there are any differences.

Comment: Both use same version of .Net - 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

When you run the console app you are communicating with the API under a different account to the one that's used when the WCF service hosted in IIS is communicating to the API.

When it's hosted in IIS, it will be using whatever is set in the Identity section of Advanced settings for the application pool. This will usually be something like 'ApplicationPoolIdentity' or 'NetworkService' etc. It may be that this account used for the Identity is unable to communicate to the API.

One test you can do to rule out issues with the account used for the Identity is to use your domain account for the Identity and see if the communication succeeds (i.e. try impersonation).